# How to pass data from textboxes to PayPal using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am trying to make a PayPal transaction in my page. I have the following fields defined:

- firstname
- lastname
- address
- email
- amount

When I click to proceed to payment it redirects my browser to PayPal correctly.  Afterwards I am able to log in using the test account and make a test payment. The problem is that when I call `print_r` to display the return_url to check the data that has been passed, I noticed that my input textbox wasn't there.

**Here is the code that posts to PayPal:**

```
$firstname = $this->input->post('firstname');
$lastname = $this->input->post('lastname');
$address = $this->input->post('address');
$email = $this->input->post('email');

$config['business'] = 'test@test.com';
$config['return'] = 'http://localhost/test/payment/return_details/';
$config['cancel_return'] = 'http://localhost/test/payment/create-job-listing/';
$config['production'] = FALSE; //Its false by default and will use sandbox
$config["first_name"] = 'asdasd';
$config["last_name"] = 'asasas';
$config['address1'] = 'new york';

$this->load->library('paypal',$config);

$this->paypal->add('Amount',0.1); 
$this->paypal->pay(); //Proccess the payment
```

Can someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

```
In your return_url put the code:

<?php 

 echo "<pre>";

 $data = file_get_contents('php://input'); //this fetches the raw input stream

 $info = explode('&',$data);

 echo "<pre>";

 print_r($info);
```

?>

//Information sent by paypal is in the input stream and this code fetches the input!!